# Where to get a collection of differently encoded text files

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I am writing a program that can detect the character-encodings of a file and then converts it to Unicode. In order to test the application I would like to have a collection of text files with different character-encodings. At least with the most common encodings. I've already been googleing for a while but didn't find any. I'm sure I am not the first one with this problem so I don't understand why I cannot find anything like that.
Does anyone know an easy way to get many differently encoded text files?

Comment: what language are you writing your program in?

Comment: @SpaceCowboy: I am writing it in C#

Comment: If I understand correctly it sounds to me like you should write another small program which creates a number of files with different encoding types. In C# you can set the encoding type of a file using a StreamWriter and using the constructor which takes an encoding (found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aadshsx.aspx). Then just use loops to create a number of files...at least that's what I would do

Comment: Is asking for test data recommendations a relevant question for SO?

Comment: Voted to close but also upvoted because I'd like to get that myself.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy : _at least that's what I would do_ and that's what I should have done.. If you make that an answer, you'll get my vote ;-)

Comment: @SpaceCowboy: Thank you for your help. I was searching for a "collection" of encoded files which are also written in the correct language. For example Chinese text encoded in Big-5, since the library I use ([Mozilla Universal Charset Detector](https://code.google.com/p/ude/)) also takes the character distribution of a certain language into account. Your idea also seems good except, that when I convert a text of Latin letters into Chinese letters, it won't make any sense and will not have anything to do with that language.

Comment: @TaW & Chris: What would be a more appropriate place to ask this question?